# Generate a polygon from an image mask?

Tags: c#, image, polygon, vector-graphics

I have an image mask (could be any format but let's keep it simple, let's say it is represented by a 256X256 array of bools where false means masked and true means not masked) containing a single shape, what would be a good way to get started to go from that to a polygon outline of said shape? The shape is guaranteed to be closed (not on the edges of the picture) and guaranteed to be the only non masked region.

So far i'm thinking of tackling it this way that seems pretty naive so i'm wondering if there's a better solution (a third party Library is not an option, i'm looking for alternative / better algorithms, but not dependencies).

- Find all masked pixels
- For each of those, ignore it if it doesn't have a non masked pixel neightboor
- Else pick it as a point for the outline (i need the outline to be "outside" the area of interest, so i pick the pixel in the masked area , not in the shape)

Is this the best one can do assumine no other properties are known about the shape? (shape is very complex and detailed, so trying to find lines isn't an option). Note that in most cases the shape is a human.

Comment: are you trying to get the [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the mask ?

Comment: Yes sounds like what i need